multinomial coefficient divisibility by 5
I have a homework problem and would appreciate some help:
Given:
s = (a+b+c+d)^10
How many coefficients in the multinomial expansion of
S are not divisible by 5?
I know that any coefficient can be expressed as:
10!/(k1!*k2!*k3!*k4!) | k1+k2+k3+k4  = 10,
I tried analyzing this form to determine when such a coefficient is divisible by 5, but I am struggling with the details.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Your mathematical expression is not typeset using MathJax so it is hard to tell what it means. Please use MathJax to display the expression properly. You will find these MathJax tutorials useful.

For Stars and Bars theory, see
this article and
this article.

Hint: $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4}~$ is not divisible by $~5~$ if and only if one of the following occurs: [1] One of the $~k_i~$ variables $~= 10.~$ [2] Two of the $~k_i~$ variables each $~= 5.$

Thank you for the hint! I’ve seen this claim before, and I managed to prove one direction: that if one of the conditions holds, then the coefficient is not divisible by 5. However, I’m struggling to prove the other direction: that if the coefficient is not divisible by 5, then one of these conditions must hold. Could you help clarify this part?

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Re my last comment, which provides a link to a MathSE protocol article, your posted question (as it currently stands) is of low quality, and therefore may not be answered by a MathSE reviewer.  My hint, plus my Stars and Bars link have given you all of the help that I am permitted to give, in this situation.  That is, I have left you with significant work to do on your own, and I am not allowed to say anything more.

If you decide that your personal path of least resistance is to conform to the protocol article, by directly editing your posted question, then, please leave a comment addressed as @user2661923.  This will flag me.  Then, I will verify the quality of your posted question.  If the posted question is then of high quality, I will provide a complete answer to the (edited - improved) posted question, unless somebody else first gives a complete answer to the posted question.

Hint: Since every multinomial coefficient has the numerator as a fixed product, how do the terms in the denominator remove factors from that product?
